# How to set a cookie with Play 2.1/Scala?

Tags: scala, cookies, playframework, playframework-2.1

[The java docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaResponse) show how to set a cookie with Java:

```
response().setCookie("theme", "blue");
```

How do I do the same with scala?

Comment: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaResults

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Ok("Hello").withCookies(Cookie("key1", "value"), Cookie("key2", "value2"))
```

Comment: Can I set the cookie without returning from the action?

Comment: No. You need to send the cookie with the action, because cookies are stored in the users browser.

Comment: I know where cookies are stored. In Play 1 you could setCookie sometime before sending the response.

Comment: Ah I see. You could define the cookies early on like this: val cookies = Seq(Cookie("key", "value")) and then pass the seq to the withCookies function like this: Ok("hello").withCookies(cookies:_*)

Comment: Yeah, a bit of a bother ... I miss Play 1.

Comment: The price of immutability :)

Comment: @JulienLafont, you misspelled "advantage" :) Knowing where all your data came from because it's in scope when you return seems like a great thing. Sorry if this is considered necroing